# how to plot a time as string versus double in matlab

Tags: matlab, time, plot

I have a data logger that stores the time and the value of a sensor,that looks like:

```
-'1:06:58'       5.0
-'1:07:00'       6.0
-'1:07:00'       7.0
-'1:07:00'       8.0
-'1:07:00'       9.0
-'1:07:02'       10.9
```

I retrieve these information in matlab and stored the values in numbers array and the date in cell array
my question is how to plot the time versus the values, here is the code I tried

```
plot (r{1},m)
```

r{1} is a cell array that has 1 column storing the dates , m is the values of the sensor

`

Comment: You should probably convert time in digital (plotable) format, like seconds or minutes

Comment: @MikhailGenkin - You don't have to.  You can override the labelling using `set` with the `XTick` and `XTickLabel` attributes.

Comment: @MikhailGenkin - Thanks :) I actually found it out by accident just fooling around with the properties of a graph.  Thanks for the vote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the first column of that data you showed is a bunch of strings and the second column is numeric, you can plot the graph using a dummy horizontal data set, and use [`set`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) with a combination of the `XTick` and `XTickLabel` flags.  Something like:

```
A = {'1:06:58', '1:07:00', '1:07:00', '1:07:00', '1:07:00','1:07:02'};
B = [5 6 7 8 9 10.9];
plot(1:numel(B), B);
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:numel(B))
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', A)
```

I get:

[image]